# Erase x axis in Google Data Studio (Google Looker)

Tags: linechart, looker-studio

I want to erase only the x axis of this line chart (the date), but I can only find the option of erasing all three axis. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: you could use the *shape→rectangle* option (*color→white*) & overlay on the x-axis date to keep it masked!

Comment: Clever approach. Didn't think about that. Thanks!